# changing animationDuration while animating

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview

Hi all i want to change animationDuration of a UIImageView while it's animating ... and want to do this 60 times a second... is there any way to do this ?
When I try to do it, the animation stops ...

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to do this? There are different curves to make things speed up or slow down.
If you do really need to do this, just start a new animation with the same parameters, but with your new duration. It should then begin the animation from wherever it had got to and carry on from there.

Comment: this doesn't work, because when the animation starts, it stops earlier  than it is about to change the image ... (because it's refreshing 60 times a second and the image changes only 10 times a second)